# Rust rd-kafka - why is the offset returned by Consumer.position invalid?

Tags: rust, apache-kafka, librdkafka, rust-rdkafka

I don't understand what the purpose of the function `Consumer.position()` is.

I wrote the below test code to experiment with it.

This is what I discovered:

- Without calling `poll()`, the Consumer does not appear to initialize
- After adding a call to `poll()`, I obtain some data from Kafka, but the Offset is set to `Invalid`

I don't understand why the offset would be set to invalid. This doesn't seem to make sense, unless this is the **committed offset value, not the most recent offset value returned by** `poll()`.

Can anyone clarify? What is the intended purpose of `Consumer.position()` ?

```
let consumer =  ...
consumer.subscribe(&topic_names).expect("subscribe failed");

// Without this, below code does nothing. Consumer not connected?
log::info!("poll: {:?}", consumer.poll(duration_30_sec));

let position = consumer.position()?;

for position_element in position.elements() {
        
    let offset = position_element.offset();

    match offset {

        rdkafka::Offset::Beginning => { }

        rdkafka::Offset::End => { }

        rdkafka::Offset::Invalid => {
            panic!("don't know what to do with Offset::Invalid, from consumer.position");
        }

        rdkafka::Offset::Offset(offset) => { }

        rdkafka::Offset::OffsetTail(offset_tail) => { }

        // Is this possible? I don't understand what "Stored" means
        rdkafka::Offset::Stored => {
            panic!("don't know what to do with Offset::Stored, from consumer.position");
        }
    }
}
```